# How many matrices do we need to add?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, intuition, random-matrices

After extensive comments by @loupblanc, and reviewing by myself, I've decided to rewrite the question, and change the matrices.

Let $p_k$ be the $k$th prime number, so that $p_1=2, p_2=3, \dots$

We will create a [Toepliz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) from some [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).  Define $R_p$ to be be a $p \times p$ circulant matrix, whose top row is filled with random numbers, and thus the rest of the circulant matrix has elements according to the definition of a circulant matrix.  Also,define:

$$A_{n,k}=M_{n,2}+M_{n,3}+\cdots+M_{n,p_k}$$

...where $M_{n,p}[i,j]=R_p[i_1,j_1]$, with $i_1=i \bmod p$ if $i \bmod p \ne 0$ and $i_1=p$ otherwise, and similarly for $j_1$.  We note that $A_{n,k}$ is therefor a Toeplitz matrix.

Given $k$, we can search for the maximum $n$ such that $A_{n,k}$ is invertible.  Let $f(k)$ be this maximum rank, i.e. $f(k)=n$.  It is then conjectured that $f(k)=2+3+5+\cdots+p_k-(k-1)$.  Is this conjecture true?

**OLD QUESTION**

A few definitions should help...  Let $R_p$ be a $p \times p$ matrix of random numbers.  Now let $M_p$ be the $n \times n$ matrix "tiled" by $R_p$.  In other words, $M_p(i,j) = R_p(i \bmod p, j \bmod p)$, or $M_p$ consists of block matrices which are equal to $R_p$:

$$M_p = \begin{bmatrix}
R_p & R_p & R_p & \dots \\
R_p & R_p & R_p & \dots \\
R_p & R_p & R_p & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, as we proceed across $M_p$, or down $M_p$, the coefficients must repeat every $p$ coefficients.

Suppose we create a matrix $A = M_2 + M_3 + M_5 + M_7 + \dots + M_\text{prime numbers} + \dots$.  In other words, we create matrices by adding together the tilings of prime number-sized block matrices.

If $A$ is then an $n \times n$ matrix, how many $M_p$'s do we need, starting with $M_2$, to create a nonsingular $A$?  To rephrase, if we start with $M_2$, add $M_3$, add $M_5$, and so on, how many do we need to add together to get a non-singular matrix (which is of course of size $n \times n$)?

I conjecture that we need roughly $n^{1/2}$ of them, but I need help proving this.  I believe this is because each $M_p$ adds approximately $p$ to the current rank of $A$.  I'm stuck, though, and could use some help.

**EDIT**

The main problem in this question seems to be what the rank of $A$ is, given the $M_p$ matrices that are used.  It seems that some of the rows and/or columns of the matrices are redundant, so the problem is basically to find out how large the rank is.

Comment: I used the wrong number in my conjecture...  I believe that we should need roughly $O(\log{(n)})$ matrices with prime-sized tilings, starting with $M_2$.

Comment: Summing $k$ such matrices (i.e., up to prime $p\sim k\log k$) should give  rank $\sim k^2\log k$, so it looks like $\log n\ll k\ll \sqrt n$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  That could have been why I came up with two different numbers.  But I could really use some pointers on where to start to prove this.  I'm really drawing a blank on this one, but I really need a proof.  From Mathematica, it looks like the matrices $M_p$ don't always contribute a rank of $p$ to the rank of $A$.  But if someone, even me, could prove a nontrivial upper bounds I'd be ecstatic

Comment: It's unclear to me that $M_p$ will be a block matrix since by the construction given some of the $R_p$ blocks will be truncated as the size of $M_p$ is $n \times n$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField:  Sorry I didn't address this.  It's assumed that the $R_p$ matrices are truncated in order to ensure that $M_p$ is always an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: @MattGroff to be fair it was given in your definition of $M_p$ and it's the only way addition of the matrices makes any sense too.

Comment: I think that your question is non-sense. For example $A\in M_{30}=M_2+M_3+M_5$ has a rank $<2+3+5=10$ with probability $1$. Yet, an interesting question about the matrix above would be : "why has this $A$ a rank equal to $8$ (and not $2+3+5=10$) with probability $1$" ?

Comment: @loupblanc:  I'm trying to get a lower bounds for the rank, in order to prove that an algorithm is correct.  So, I need to know that the rank of the matrices above is at least above the threshold that I conjecture.  This question is important to me because of this, so it's not nonsense to me.  That's why I'm attempting to appeal to someone with knowledge in a field such as linear algebra, and I see that you seem to have knowledge in it.  If this is nonsense, I wish you would help me ask a better question if this seems to be nonsense.  But there is a reasoning behind this question.

Comment: @loupblanc: Perhaps if I clarify 2 points you will will change your mind...  First off, the matrices $R_\text{prime}$ must have a prime number of rows and columns.  So there really is no such thing as $M_{30}$ in this context.  Secondly, I'm trying to find the $\textit{maximum}$ rank of the matrices.  I think that if you experiment, you'll find that the maximum rank is equal to the sum of the prime numbers used, minus $(q-1)$, where $q$ is the total number of primes used.  I hope that this clarifies things.

Comment: I noticed that the singular properties of the new Toeplitz matrices are somewhat addressed in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154811/probability-a-random-toeplitz-matrix-is-singular/202918

Comment: @MattGroff You have neglected to specify what is the probability distribution of the random matrices $R_p$. Do you assume the entries of the top row of $R_p$ are independent and have the same distribution? Do you assume that the distribution of each entry is a standard Gaussian distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$?

Comment: @pre-kidney:  All entries of the top row are supposed to be independent with the same distribution.  You can assume that they have a standard Gaussian distribution.  As for their values, they are essentially either bits with this distribution, or if it doesn't hinder evaluation, ranging from $0$ to $z-1$ for a natural number $z$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Some remarks about the writing of the question.

I rarely read a so unclear post. Let $p_k$ be the $k^{th}$ prime number (of the list $2,3,5,\cdots$). You must absolutely explicitly define the matrix $A_{n,k}\in M_n$, for example, as follows:

$A_{n,k}=M_{n,2}+M_{n,3}+\cdots+M_{n,p_k}$ where $M_{n,p}[i,j]=R_p[i_1,j_1]$, with $i_1=i\; mod\; p$ if $i\; mod\; p<>0$ and $i_1=p$ otherwise (similar definition for $j_1$). In particular $M_{n,p}$ is not tiled by the $R_p$ because you use scissors!

For a fixed $n$, you search the minimum of $k$ s.t. $A_{n,k}$ is invertible. In general, such a problem is difficult; yet, in $M_{n,p_k}$ (the last matrix), there are still many copies of the matrix $R_{p_k}$ and I think that the problem is feasible.

2. That follows is the result of some experiments (until $k=23$).

i) I think that it is better to consider that $k$ is given and to research the maximum of the $n$ s.t. $A_{n,k}$ is invertible. Indeed, when the $R_p$ are randomly chosen, $A_{n,k}$ is "always" invertible or "always" non-invertible. Moreover, if $A_{n,k}$ is invertible, then the $A_{m,k}$, with $m<n$, are "always" invertible.

ii) Then let $f(k)$ be this maximal $n$. Several calculations seem to "prove":

Conjecture (it may be the meaning of the last Matt Groff's comment): $f(k)=2+3\cdots+p_k-k+1$.

I think that it is much better to rewrite your post, using  the lines above (definition of $A_{n,k}$ and conjecture).

Comment: Thank you very much for your considerations.  I have rewritten the question, and also changed it because I realized that I need circulant and Toeplitz matrices, as opposed to the old matrices.  I sincerely hope that this makes the question much better, and hopefully easier to solve.